# How can I group by FormArray by one of the FormControl

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to group by the Formarray by the formControl value of treeType. so what I did:

```
 groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
    const map = new Map();
    list.forEach((item) => {
      const key = keyGetter(item);
      const collection = map.get(key);
      if (!collection) {
        map.set(key, [item]);
      } else {
        collection.push(item);
      }
    });
    return map;
  } 
  calculationTreesDetails(inputFormGroup: any[]) {
  

    let grouped = this.groupBy(inputFormGroup.map(x => x.controls), o => o.treeType.value.code)
}
```

now I have mapping array but how can I sum some value in each group?

[image]

MY GROUP ARRAY

```
0: {2 => Array(2)}
key: 2
value: Array(2)
0: {numTreeORpolygon: FormControl, treeORpolygonID: FormControl, quantityOfTrees: FormControl, treeType: FormControl, actionReasonID: FormControl, …}
1: {numTreeORpolygon: FormControl, treeORpolygonID: FormControl, quantityOfTrees: FormControl, treeType: FormControl, actionReasonID: FormControl, …}
length: 2

: {4 => Array(1)}
key: 4
value: Array(1)
0:
actionReasonDetails: FormControl {asyncValidator: null, pristine: false, touched: true, validator: ƒ, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
actionReasonID: FormControl {asyncValidator: null, pristine: false, touched: true, validator: ƒ, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
areaImgGUID: FormArray {asyncValidator: null, pristine: true, touched: false, validator: ƒ, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}

treeLocation: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, pristine: true, touched: false, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
treeORpolygonID: FormControl {asyncValidator: null, pristine: false, touched: true, validator: ƒ, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
treeSpecieValue: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null,
```

or arrays as object how can I iterate them?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Took your code, made a dummy array, tested it and it works. In your example you've provided a breakdown of the ***this.treeInfoModel.controls***. In your attempt, you're using ***inputFormGroup***.

Check what ***inputFormGroup*** is equal to, most likely it is not the same as ***this.treeInfoModel.controls***.

```
let inputFormGroup = [
  {
    value: {
      treeType: { code: 7 },
    },
  },
];

let c = from(inputFormGroup)
  .pipe(
    groupBy((c) => c.value.treeType.code),
    mergeMap((group$) => group$.pipe(toArray()))
  )
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Comment: thank you very much, I found the way to my desire array. but after I grouped the array, lets say I have 2 items from type x and 3 items of type y, how I iterate the array and find sum between each group? thanks again

Comment: include a sample of your grouped array using JSON.stringify(grouped) and include it in your Question

Comment: ok I edited the question

Comment: You forgot to use JSON.stringify() the output provided is un-parseable.

Comment: so How can I do it? how can I iterate the map value?

Comment: I edited the post, even if I have arrays of the grouped element as objeect how can I iterate them?

Comment: groupBy((c) => c.value.treeType.code), tap( (g) => console.log(JSON.stringify(g)))